bind parameters to callback server function in NextJS 15
I am trying to send a React Server Function as a callback into a client component but the parameters need to be bound before passing the callback.
Basically i want to create a general YesNoModalDialog, which gets the function to call on "yes" from a different component. I use jotai as state management system but this doesnt play a role.
Suppose the following code:
YesNoModalDialog.tsx
"use client";
export default function YesNoDialog() {
   const [yesNoDialogState, setYesNoDialogState] =
        useAtom(yesNoDialogStateAtom);
   return (
    <Dialog>
      <button onClick={() => {yesNoDialogState.func()}}>
          Yes
      </button>
    </Dialog>
   )
}

SpecificOpenModalButton.tsx
"use client";
import { myServerFunction } from "@/MySF"; // standard NextJS server func
const [yesNoDialogState, setYesNoDialogState] =
        useAtom(yesNoDialogStateAtom);
return (
    <Button
        onClick={() => {
                setYesNoDialogState({
                    ...yesNoDialogState,
                    open: true,
                    func: myServerFunction,
                });
            }}
        >
            OpenModalButton
        </Button>
    );
}

So at this point i just call the server function which i pass as a callback to the modal and it works. But i need specific parameters, that only my OpenModalButton knows which i want to bind before passing it to the modal. So i thought i can do this:
const paramBoundFunc = myServerFunction.bind("oneParameter");
setYesNoDialogState({
     ...yesNoDialogState,
     open: true,
     func: paramBoundFunc,
});

But of course this doesnt work. In fact i cant access "this" in a server action (aka server function) as per error reporting from NextJS. So my basic question is, how can i pass a server function into a client component as a callback where the parameters are defined from the caller. Perhaps this isnt even pssible but i want a very generic modal box which doesnt know anyhing about the related business function being called on clicking "yes".
Or is the only solution to use a anonymous function in my ModalButton like this:
<Button
   onClick={() => {
       setYesNoDialogState({
          ...yesNoDialogState,
          open: true,
          func: async() => {await myServerFunction("myParam")},
        });
   }}>
      OpenModalButton
</Button>

